# Which is best/performance putting wrapper top of SOAP service or creating new REST full service?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

All services are running in SOAP. for now they client asking us to provide a REST service.

I have two options

1. Write a wrapper for existing SOAP services to provide REST full services
2. Brand new REST full service.

Which is better (in performance perspective)?

Comment: From the one hand you have one light layer (Rest) and on the other hand, you have two layers (Rest that delegates to SOAP) which one of them (SOAP) has more overhead. The choice about performance is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single service usually has better performance than a service and a proxy (wrapper).

However SOAP and REST (with JSON) services are approximately equal in performance, you'll come to see that in parsing/serializing XML and JSON to objects representations (with jackson or JAXB), the object creation is the most demanding part, not reading JSON or XML format. The overall impact on performance is probably lower than 5 percent - a single core can usually top 50 mb/s in parse/serialize capacity.

The above also implies that if you already have a very optimized SOAP backend, probably going with the proxy is the right choice.

Moving from SOAP to REST you should use a tool like swagger (OpenAPI) to define the service in as much detail as the SOAP service. Note that REST services also can use XML, but probably that is not what your client is expecting.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, we decided to go with proxy (wrapper).

Comment: hey @kannansaravanan I have same need, I have a soap based XML responding service, now I have to write api around that, what apporach did you follow?

Answer (score -1):

**Definitely Writing a new Rest web service would be the better choice because**

1. Rest is light weight due to statelesness(due to HTTP protocol).No state is maintained.hence keep ur resources free.
2. You don't require a schema as you need for soap webservice.Thus serializing and deserializing is also not required.Thus makes performance far better
3. Testing a rest service would be easy for you.
4. Even rest is supported to develop an App on the based of REST API you have developed if u require in future.
5. Rest supports multiple data excahnge formats for ex : json,text etc.
6. Rest can be easily integrated with high-end frameworks like Spring etc.
7. You may use better documentation for your service via Swagger for Rest to keep knowledge about your service for business understanding.